# we need to find unit vector along the reflected ray.

Tags: mathematical-physics

A ray of light on a plane mirror comes along a vector $i+j-k$

The normal on incidence point is along $i+j$

we need to find  unit vector along the reflected ray.

I am not able to solve and draw the picture. could any one explain me what is going on?

answer given is $-{1\over\sqrt{3}}(i+j+k)$

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that $u$ is the vector of incoming ray, $n$ is the normal, and $v$ is the reflected ray. The normal component of $u$ is 
$$\frac{u\cdot n}{|n|^2}n$$ 
This is the component that must be reversed. We reverse it by subtracting twice of it: 
$$v = u - 2\,\frac{u\cdot n}{|n|^2 } n$$ 
is the reflected vector. 
Here $$v = i+j-k -2\,\frac{2}{2}(i+j) = -i-j-k$$
which you are then asked to normalize.